# What happened to the cryopod?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

When the colony ship Covenant has suffered some severe damage

> from the neutrino burst

some people aboard the ship die.

> In particular, the captain's cryopod cannot be opened in time, and he burns to death.

**Why? What happened to that cryopod?**

> I realize the straightforward answer is "There was fire in the cryopod." I saw that. However, *why* was the interior of the pod incinerated; what could cause a sudden fire in there?

At least on-screen, none of the crew seemed to be concerned about establishing the specific nature of the technical failure, which makes me think that the observed issue was well-known (or else, it would seem like it should be a major concern as it could happen to any of the other cryopods of all the stored colonists, as well).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [novelisation of the film](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien:_Covenant_(novel)) indicates that the accident caused sparking inside the machines that fed the cryo-pods their supply of breathable atmosphere.

> *Lights flashed around her and from several wall-mounted panels, **sparks
>   erupting in satanic electronic celebration.** There was also smoke.
>   Smoke in a spaceship was a bad sign indeed. At the moment, the
>   scrubbers in the circulation system were barely keeping up with it.
>   Alarms assailed her ears.*

The change in atmosphere in the pod was immediately recognisable as a fire risk.

> *Swirling vapor began to accumulate beneath the transparent lid,
>   masking their view of the sleeper. That was most definitely not
>   normal. **Worse still, she knew what it signaled, and what would happen
>   if—***

Fire seems to have spread along the tubes that fed atmosphere into the cryo-pod,  resulting in an ignition.

> *Inside the pod, an explosion. Compared to the cacophony of other sounds throughout the hypersleep bay, it wasn’t loud, but it was significant enough to cause both men to draw back reflexively. **On the other side of the clear plastic lid there was a sudden increase in vapor and for the first time… fire.** Uttering a primal whine, a hysterical Daniels threw herself onto the pod, clawing desperately at the ineffective rescue device.
>
>   Within, her husband’s eyes suddenly snapped open as he finally began to awaken. Through the vapor and the intensifying flames, there was recognition. His gaze locked on hers. It lasted only for an instant. Just like his smile. Both were his last.
>
>   Daniels continued to scream, and the inside of the pod was engulfed in flames as if someone had tossed a torch onto a pile of combustible material. Though initially resistant to fire, when the interior finally caught it burned hot and fast. Everything ignited—bed, support tubing, instruments… Jacob.*